# how to make display cart shows different size yet maintaining other size already added

Tags: php, forms, session

The coding I'm working on right now is almost correct: It does add another column when i choose different size and submit the form but it replace the previous output with the new one.

It was suppose to be like this

```
CART
___________________________________________

Item/Size            |QTY  | AMOUNT(price) |
Orange POLO Size: XS | 1   | 43.00         |
Orange POLO Size: L  | 1   | 43.00         |
____________________________________________
```

but instead it becomes like this

```
CART
___________________________________________

Item/Size            |QTY  | AMOUNT(price) |
Orange POLO Size: L  | 2   | 86.00         |
Orange POLO Size: L  | 2   | 86.00         |
____________________________________________
```

How to make it add new size but maintaining the previous size that's already added?

```
<?php session_start();

$products =  $_POST["item_name"]."Size:".$_POST["size"];
$key= $_POST["size"];
$amounts = $_POST["amount"];


if ( !isset($_SESSION["total"]) ) {

$_SESSION["total"] = 0;
   for ($i=0; $i< count($products); $i++) {
    $_SESSION["qty"][$i] = 0;
   $_SESSION["amounts"][$i] = 0;
  }
 }  

 //---------------------------
 //Add
 if ( isset($_POST["submit1"]) )
   {
     $i = $_POST["submit1"]; 
     $qty = $_SESSION["qty"][$i] + 1;
     $_SESSION["amounts"][$i] = $amounts * $qty;
     $_SESSION["cart"][$key] = $i;
     $_SESSION["qty"][$i] = $qty;
     $_SESSION["products"] = $products;
 }

  //view cart

 <br/><br/>
 <h2>Cart</h2>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <th width="300px">Product</th>
 <th width="10px">&nbsp;</th>
 <th>Qty</th>
 <th width="10px">&nbsp;</th>
 <th>Amount</th><br>

 <th width="10px">&nbsp;</th>
 <th>Action</th>
 </tr>

 <?php
 $total = 0;
 foreach ( $_SESSION["cart"] as $i) {
 ?>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo ($_SESSION["products"]);?></td>
 <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
 <td><?php echo( $_SESSION["qty"][$i] ); ?></td>
 <td width="100px">&nbsp;</td>
 <td><?php echo( $_SESSION["amounts"][$i] ); ?></td>
 <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
 <td><a href="?delete=<?php echo($i); ?>">Delete from cart</a></td>
 </tr>
 <?php
  $total = $total + $_SESSION["amounts"][$i];
      }
       $_SESSION["total"] = $total;
        ?>
          <tr>
   <td colspan="7">Total : <?php echo($total); ?></td>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
   <td colspan="5"><a href="?reset=true">Reset Cart</a></td>
   </tr>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

The form :

```
<form action="viewcart.php" method="post">
    <div style="background:#eeeeee; padding:10px; border-style:double; font-size:24px;">
                    Size
<input type="hidden" value="SIZE"/>
<select name="size" style="width:97%">
   <option value="XS">XS</option>
   <option value="S">S</option>
   <option value="M">M</option>
   <option value="L">L</option>
   <option value="XL">XL</option>
</select>
</div>

  <!-- item name -->
      <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Polo Orange"/>
  <!-- item price -->
      <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="43"/>

  <button class="button button5" type="submit" name="submit1" border="0" style="margin-top:20px;">ADD TO CHART</button>
```

Comment: This is not a correct syntax: `$_POST["item_name"]."Size:".$_POST["size"]';` It should be `$_POST["item_name"]["Size".$_POST["size"]]';`

Comment: Where is your `form`? Or is this script triggerd via REST-API-Call. Need more info please :)

Comment: @karasci_maci That one is ok. I put the ."Size:". between the two just to mention the value display of $_POST["size"] is size of the tshirt. But thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @Glufu already put it on my post, sir :D

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give your `button` a value inside your `form`. But in your PHP-Script you take this `value` and use it as an index (`$i = $_POST["submit1"];`). This will crash everything because you overwrite the erverything.

Try to add a value like this

```
<button class="button button5" type="submit" name="submit1" border="0" style="margin-top:20px;" value="<?php echo count($_SESSION["qty"]) ?>">ADD TO CHART</button>
```

or generate a new index inside your PHP-Script like this

```
 //---------------------------
 //Add
 if ( isset($_POST["submit1"]) )
   {
     $i = count($_SESSION["qty"]); 
     $qty = $_SESSION["qty"][$i] + 1;
     $_SESSION["amounts"][$i] = $amounts * $qty;
     $_SESSION["cart"][$key] = $i;
     $_SESSION["qty"][$i] = $qty;
     $_SESSION["products"] = $products;
 }
```